# How do I make this filter/group visual go away?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook 2016.  I feel like I've tried everything and looked everywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

1. Change your view from the compact view to "Single" (or any view that shows column headers):

   [image]
2. Right click on any header and deselect "Group by Box"

   [image]
3. Change your view back.

   [image]

Voilà!